# Github API - Getting only year from date information

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, github

i am trying to put my repos to my personal web site, but there is no information about this, I want to take only year info from JSON data

```
"created_at": "2017-07-17T09:13:40Z",
"updated_at": "2017-07-18T13:49:04Z",
"pushed_at": "2017-07-19T05:13:28Z",
```

How can we take **only year** data from JSON query

http://jsfiddle.net/nT5wY/322/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse String presentation to Date object. Then you can query that object for values, like year:

```
for( i in result ) {
    var created_at = new Date(result[i].created_at)
    $("#repo_list").append(
    "<li><a href='" + result[i].html_url + "' target='_blank'>" +
        created_at.getFullYear() + "</a></li>"
    );
    console.log("i: " + i);
}
```